# Webpack jQuery and jQuery.lazy() TypeError: q is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

how can I bundle `jquery` and `jquery.lazy` with webpack? - Everytime I try this, I got an error.

My error is the following in the debug console of my browser:

```
TypeError: q is undefined
```

The rest is working fine. Maybe you can see that I've done something wrong.

My package.json:

```
{
      "name": "mrd-apple",
      "version": "1i.0.0",
      "description": "mrd Apple",
      "main": "webpack.config.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jquery-lazy": "^1.7.10",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "webpack": "^4.29.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
      }
    }
}
```

My webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
var OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function(env) {
    return {
        entry: ['./src/js/index.js'],
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery'
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
                // both options are optional
                filename: "[name].css",
                chunkFilename: "[id].css"
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
                assetNameRegExp: /\.optimize\.css$/g,
                cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
                cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
                    preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
                },
                canPrint: true
            })
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            options: {
                                // you can specify a publicPath here
                                // by default it use publicPath in webpackOptions.output
                                publicPath: '../'
                            }
                        },
                        "css-loader"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                new UglifyJsPlugin({
                    cache: true,
                    parallel: true,
                    sourceMap: true // set to true if you want JS source maps
                }),
                new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

Content of index.js

```
// JS 
// require('./jquery.lazy'); 
require('./lightslider'); 
require('./simple-lightbox'); 
require('./init'); 

// CSS 
require('./../css/index.css');
```

Comment: Where are you getting that error? I mean which file is throwing that error?

Comment: In the console, when I open my url.

Comment: There is no need to have 'jQuery' dependency because jquery-lazy is dependent on jquery and get installed along with it - https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy/blob/master/package.json. The question similar to yours is asked in the github issues - https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy/issues/195.

Comment: When I only install jquery-lazy, it is the same problem. - And jQuery is not defined.

Comment: so you have imports for jquery stuff in the executed code right ? and it works fine without packaging ?

Comment: So like you see I import first jQuery and then Jquery lazy. With jQuery it is no problem. I can use it. I import jQuery as a package not as a file in webpack bundle. When I import both via .js file in bundle it is also not working. Maybe something else is wrong?

Comment: @yfain you need to define jQuery inside of `<head>`. You can use -           
`<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>` inside of `<head></head>`.

Comment: Are you kidding me?

Comment: @yfain, what's in your index.js file?

Comment: // JS
// require('./jquery.lazy');
require('./lightslider');
require('./simple-lightbox');
require('./init');

// CSS
require('./../css/index.css');

Comment: Please put the index.js inside a code block in the question

Comment: I have added the index.js into the first post.

Answer (score -1):

your issue is with how you are trying to use require.js

First of all, there are issues with your package.json:

- both `webpack` and `postcss-loader` are devDependencies.
- Also your version is invalid.
- I had to add the following as devDependencies: `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`, `mini-css-extract-plugin`, `optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin`

The issue, however, is how you are trying to include these libraries.

When using require.js with a package.json and webpack, you would not be trying to require the .js file itself, instead you would either `require('npm-package-name')` or, better yet, `import NpmPackageName from 'npm-package-name'`; See: [Dependency Management](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/)

If you wanted to load a library through HTML on your page and instead just reference it in your source, you can do that using webpack externals. See: [Webpack Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

for reference, here are my versions of your files:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mrd-apple",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "mrd Apple",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-lazy": "^1.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
// require('jquery');
// require('jquery-lazy');

import $ from 'jquery';
import jqueryLazy from 'jquery-lazy';
```

NOTE: I was unable to produce the exact error you provided, but assume it's due to the project setup itself.